# VBA nested loops variable assignment

Tags: excel, vba, variables, if-statement, nested-loops

I need to loop through the rows of my excel spreadsheet, and if a particular value is present in one column, copy the value from another column in the same row to another part of the spreadsheet.  I also need to sum sets of values from another column based on the value in the first column.

Overall my code is working well, except for one small part.  To avoid iterating through and copying rows that would have duplicate values, I want to reset the value of "x" (my row counter) based on the lowest row that I got to, in my nested loop statement below.  In this case, I want "x" to iterate to the value of "GoDown", assuming that "GoDown" is greater than 0.  However, my code hangs when I do this.  It works fine when I avoid the final "if...else" statement, and just use "x = x+1".

Can anyone tell me what's going on, or how to fix it?  It hangs at the second range assignment statement, which seems like an odd place.  Thanks so much for any help, and please let me know if I can clarify anything.

```
Sub NumberCheck()

Dim x As Integer
Dim GoDown As Integer
Dim n As Integer
x = 2
n = 0

Do Until Range("D" & x) = ""

If Range("D" & x) > 50 Then
Range("F" & x).Value = Range("A" & x).Value
Range("G" & x).Value = Range("D" & x).Value
GoDown = x

    Do Until Range("C" & GoDown) = 0 
    n = n + Range("C" & GoDown).Value
    Range("J" & x).Value = Range("B" & GoDown).Value
    GoDown = GoDown + 1
    Loop

Range("H" & x).Value = n
n = 0
End If

If GoDown > 0 Then
x = GoDown
Else
x = x + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I solved my own question.  I had accidentally created an infinite loop!  I'm leaving this up in case it helps someone else.

I didn't realize that when I iterated "x" to "GoDown", sometimes "GoDown" would be lower than "x", thus creating my infinite loop.  To solve the problem, I added an AND statement to the final If...Else, to make sure that "x" always gets larger.  Now everything works fine.  Shows what rookie I am, I guess.

    If GoDown > 0 And x < GoDown Then
    x = GoDown
    Else
    x = x + 1
    End If

Comment: Good job! Please add your solution as the accepted answer so everyone will know it is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question.  I had accidentally created an infinite loop!  I'm leaving this up in case it helps someone else.

I didn't realize that when I iterated "x" to "GoDown", sometimes "GoDown" would be lower than "x", thus creating my infinite loop.  To solve the problem, I added an AND statement to the final If...Else, to make sure that "x" always gets larger.  Now everything works fine.  Shows what rookie I am, I guess.

```
If GoDown > 0 And x < GoDown Then
x = GoDown
Else
x = x + 1
End If
```